Object Detection in MATLAB with a polygon >>4
I'm trying to modify the code provided to successfully detect the elephant in the desk image. It is expected to identify the region containing the object of interest with a polygon (number of edges >>4) coarsely following the elephant shape but as I tried many times I've always obtained a 4-edges polygon even with trying with ginput(12) so there may be problems in upgrading parameters.
This was the initial code (the images are already b&w):
clear all
close all
clc
%% read images
% template
boxImage = imread('./immaginiObjectDetection/stapleRemover.jpg');
% desk
sceneImage = imread('./immaginiObjectDetection/clutteredDesk.jpg');
figure(1), clf, imshow(boxImage)
figure(2), clf, imshow(sceneImage)
% figure(1), clf, imagesc(boxImage)
% figure(2), clf, imagesc(sceneImage)
tic
%% keypoint detection
boxPoints = detectSURFFeatures(boxImage);
scenePoints = detectSURFFeatures(sceneImage);
figure(1), clf
imshow(boxImage), hold on
plot(selectStrongest(boxPoints,100)), hold off
figure(2), clf
imshow(sceneImage), hold on
plot(selectStrongest(scenePoints,100)), hold off
%% keypoint description
[boxFeatures, boxPoints]=extractFeatures(boxImage, boxPoints);
[sceneFeatures, scenePoints]=extractFeatures(sceneImage, scenePoints);
%% feature matching
boxPairs = matchFeatures(boxFeatures, sceneFeatures);
matchedBoxPoints = boxPoints(boxPairs(:,1),:);
matchedScenePoints = scenePoints(boxPairs(:,2),:);
showMatchedFeatures(boxImage, sceneImage, matchedBoxPoints, ...
    matchedScenePoints, 'montage');
%% geometric consistency check
[tform, inlierBoxPoints, inlierScenePoints]=...
    estimateGeometricTransform(matchedBoxPoints,...
    matchedScenePoints,'affine');
showMatchedFeatures(boxImage, sceneImage, inlierBoxPoints, ...
    inlierScenePoints, 'montage');
%% bounding box drawing
boxPoly = [1 1;
    size(boxImage,2) 1;
    size(boxImage,2) size(boxImage,1);
    1 size(boxImage,1);
    1 1];
newBoxPoly=transformPointsForward(tform,boxPoly);
figure, clf
imshow(sceneImage), hold on
line(newBoxPoly(:,1),newBoxPoly(:,2),'Color','y')
hold off
toc
%% more precise bounding box
figure, clf
imshow(boxImage)
[x,y]=ginput(4);
%%
x=[x; x(1)];
y=[y; y(1)];
newBoxPoly=transformPointsForward(tform,[x y]);
figure, clf
imshow(sceneImage), hold on
line(newBoxPoly(:,1),newBoxPoly(:,2),'Color','y')
hold off
toc

This is how I tried to change it:
clear all
close all
clc
%% read images
% template
boxImage = imread('./immaginiObjectDetection/elephant.jpg');
% desk
sceneImage = imread('./immaginiObjectDetection/clutteredDesk.jpg');
figure(1), clf, imshow(boxImage)
figure(2), clf, imshow(sceneImage)
% figure(1), clf, imagesc(boxImage)
% figure(2), clf, imagesc(sceneImage)
tic
%% keypoint detection
boxPoints = detectSURFFeatures(boxImage, 'MetricThreshold', 1000);
scenePoints = detectSURFFeatures(sceneImage);
figure(1), clf
imshow(boxImage), hold on
plot(selectStrongest(boxPoints,100)), hold off
figure(2), clf
imshow(sceneImage), hold on
plot(selectStrongest(scenePoints,100)), hold off
%% keypoint description
[boxFeatures, boxPoints]=extractFeatures(boxImage, boxPoints);
[sceneFeatures, scenePoints]=extractFeatures(sceneImage, scenePoints);
%% feature matching
boxPairs = matchFeatures(boxFeatures, sceneFeatures, 'MatchThreshold', 30, ...
    'Method','Exhaustive');
matchedBoxPoints = boxPoints(boxPairs(:,1),:);
matchedScenePoints = scenePoints(boxPairs(:,2),:);
showMatchedFeatures(boxImage, sceneImage, matchedBoxPoints, ...
    matchedScenePoints, 'montage');
%% geometric consistency check
[tform, inlierBoxPoints, inlierScenePoints]=...
    estimateGeometricTransform(matchedBoxPoints,...
    matchedScenePoints,'projective', 'Confidence', 90, 'MaxDistance', 3);
showMatchedFeatures(boxImage, sceneImage, inlierBoxPoints, ...
    inlierScenePoints, 'montage');
%% bounding box drawing
boxPoly = [1 1;
    size(boxImage,2) 1;
    size(boxImage,2) size(boxImage,1);
    1 size(boxImage,1);
    1 1];
newBoxPoly=transformPointsForward(tform,boxPoly);
figure, clf
imshow(sceneImage), hold on
line(newBoxPoly(:,1),newBoxPoly(:,2),'Color','y')
hold off
toc
%% more precise bounding box
figure, clf
imshow(boxImage)
[x,y]=ginput(12);
%%
x=[x; x(1)];
y=[y; y(1)];
newBoxPoly=transformPointsForward(tform,[x y]);
figure, clf
imshow(sceneImage), hold on
line(newBoxPoly(:,1),newBoxPoly(:,2),'Color','y')
hold off
toc


I really don't understand this question. There's two blocks of nearly identical code. It finds a template in a larger image, draws the template bounding box, lets the user draw a polygon around the template image, and then draws that polygon. Why two nearly identical blocks of code? Is all of this code necessary for your question? What is the problem? What have you done to debug the problem? Have you tried to reduce the code to only the part that doesn't behave like you expect?

Hi, the first code is the code that it has been given to me, the second one regards my modifies. The problem is that I need a polygon with a lot more than 4 edges to identify the elephant in that picture but I always obtain a 4 edges polygon which is not accurate. The polygon is not manually drawn but automatically from the algorithm

ginput requires user interaction. ginput(12) will ask for twelve points, that you have to give by clicking with the mouse in the window. These points will then form the vertices of a polygon that is drawn. If you don't click with the mouse, the program will stall at the ginput line and wait until you either click 12 times or stop the program running.
